# VS Code Extension: Add custom command to right click menu in file explorer for any file type

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, right-click

I have a command that I want to appear on the menu whenever you right click on any type of file in the file explorer on visual studio code.

This configuration from my package.json file works when I right click on **typescript** files, but what option should I use so that it does this on **all types of files**?

```
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "uploadCurrentFile.command",
                "title": "Upload Current File"
            }
        ],
        "menus": {
            "explorer/context": [{
                "when": "resourceLangId == typescript",
                "command": "uploadCurrentFile.command",
                "group": "navigation"
            }]
        }
    },
```

So that it pops up at the top of this menu
[Screenshot of right click menu on file explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHSuv.png) for every type of file.

Comment: `.gitignore` is not a typescript file

Comment: @rioV8 Ohhh that makes a lot of sense. Is there a way I can change the "when" attribute so that this appears on any type of file then?

Comment: just remove the `when` it defaults to `true` or set it to `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, just remove the when clause, or explicitly set it to `true`.